# Deleting a all files in a folder except one folder in windows command prompt or batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a way to delete all files in folder but except one folder through windows batch script..can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test this - it should work.

For EX:To remove all files and folder except cd folder inside abc

pushd "d:\abc\cd" && rd /s /q "d:\abc" 2>nul

Comment: This does delete the contents of "d:\abc\cd".

Answer (score 2):

In windows powershell, Use the below command to remove all files and folder except one

```
Remove-Item c:\<Path to Folder>\* -exclude *<folder you don't want to remove>*
```

Answer (score 1):

This lists all the files (and only the files) in the current directory:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

to delete a folder you can do:

```
RMDIR \"FOLDERNAME" /S /Q
```

you can compare two values in windows batch file as:

```
 if NOT "%SubFolderName%" == "folder-name-you-do-not-want-to-delete"
         // delete the folder.
```

I hope you can connect the dots...